# Push notif failed with curl

Tags: android, windows, curl

I am testing push notification for android development and i am currently use windows as pusher. When I run this command in terminal , i have this error :
'''{"error":"Bad Request","description":"Failed to read body as a JSON object"}''' 
for more details :
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD0HA.png)

Answer (score 1):

Solved by changing the format of json data (for **windows** users)
from :  **-d '{"interests":["hello"],"fcm":{"notification":{"title":"Hello","body":"Hello, world!"}}}'**

to : **-d "{\"interests\":[\"hello\"],\"fcm\":{\"notification\":{\"title\":\"Hello\",\"body\":\"Hello, world!\"}}}"**