# curl command is not executing push notification using pusher

Tags: android, curl, push-notification, pusher

I am working on Android application using ESP32. I want a system, where, when I press button (hardware button) it send a notification to an android app. I have connected the data to firebase and used pusher to send notification. My device is integrate. But, I am unable to execute push notification curl command.
When I execute curl command (I even downloaded curl.exe and set the path):

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer **Secret Key**" \
 -X POST "https://**Instance ID**.pushnotifications.pusher.com/publish_api/v1/instances/**Instance ID**/publishes" \
 -d '{"interests":["hello" ,"fcm":{"notification":{"title":"Hello", "body":"Hello, world!"}}}'
```

I got error in command prompt, like this:

```sh
C:\Windows\system32>curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \
C:\Windows\system32>     -H "Authorization: Bearer **Secret Key**" \
'-H' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\Windows\system32>     -X POST "https://**Instance ID**.pushnotifications.pusher.com/publish_api/v1/instances/**Instance ID**/publishes" \
'-X' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\Windows\system32>     -d '{"interests":["hello"],"fcm":{"notification":{"title":"Hello", "body":"Hello, world!"}}}'
'-d' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

The entire block should be a single command, but it seems your command line is executing a line at a time.

Try the below, which I should run as a single line command

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer **Secret Key**"  -X POST "https://**InstanceID**.pushnotifications.pusher.com/publish_api/v1/instances/**Instance ID**/publishes" -d '{"interests":["hello" ,"fcm":{"notification": "title":"Hello", "body":"Hello, world!"}}}'
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I made changes as per you asked me. It works, but it's showing again a new error which I am unable to understand. The error is : {"error":"Bad Request","description":"Failed to read body as a JSON object"}
curl: (3) unmatched brace in URL position 6:
,fcm:{notification:

Comment: I got the error solve from this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839567/push-notif-failed-with-curl Thank you so much for the help @doydoy

Comment: No problem, thanks for sharing the solution - it is an interesting find!